# Сортировка в sqlite и буква "Ё"

Tags: android, sqlite, локаль

Имею БД с русскими словами, они должны выводиться по порядку. В БД есть слова которые начинаются на буквы "ё" и "е". Проблема в том, что видимо sqlite считает, что это одна и та же буква и сортировка работает некорректно, например:

```
дамба
дистанция
егерь
еда
ёжик
ездок
енот
жабры
```

Для запроса слов использую такой код:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT word FROM words ORDER BY word COLLATE LOCALIZED", null);
```

В DBHelper-е указываю локаль:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setLocale(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы сортировка происходила согласно русскому алфавиту, т.е, слова начинающиеся с буквы "ё" должны быть после слов на букву "е", а не вперемешку. Как можно исправить сортировку?

Comment: Убрать COLLATE не пробовали?

Comment: @itvdonsk, пробовал, тогда слова на букву "ё" становятся первыми и сортировка идет с учетом регистра: сначала список слов с большой буквы, потом с маленькой.

Comment: а использовать COLLATE NOCASE? Это кстати не сработает для кириллицы :( И вообще в андроиде большие проблемы у SQLite с кириллицей

Comment: @itvdonsk, не пробовал, вроде как это действительно и не должно работать. Согласно документации оно работает только с латиницей.

Comment: поэтому остается только два варианта - тащить за собой sqlite http://habrahabr.ru/post/122408/ или делать еще колонку с одинаковым регистром и искать\сортировать по ней

Comment: @itvdonsk, в общем-то я пришел к такому же выводу. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @itvdonsk: Вы бы оформили как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

существует два варианта:

- тащить за собой sqlite: http://habrahabr.ru/post/122408/;
- делать еще колонку с одинаковым регистром и искать/сортировать по ней.

ответ взят из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429960/178576#comment442564_429960) пользователя [itvdonsk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183571).